# ASP.NET MVC5 area section override route action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm encountering issues on controller routes when using area section. My home controller (located in the main root) has an action result for logout/signout session. I created a "configuration" area in order to have a subfolder like structuring. When i run the web app redirected to the configuration url when i perform a log-out, the ref url is configuration/home/signout instead of home/signout.

I tried to add a MapRoute inside the ConfigurationAreaRegistration but the problem still exists. How can i correct the url for signout under Area section?

Comment: please upload related code.

Comment: Please check your controller namespaces and make sure they match the area folders. For example, your main route definition should use `MyApp.Controllers` as the namespace, and your Admin area route registration should use `MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers` as the namespace

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
What i did is to to set the Url.Action area attribute to null.